# GitHub for Windows can't log in

Tags: github, github-for-windows

When i install GitHub i can't log in using my acount credentials.
I get the error

```
Login Error
unable to retrieve your user info from the server. A proxy server might be interfering with the request
```

I tried reinstalling several times, with no success.
Also, i read somewhere that someone had a problem with rasman.dll, but i did run

```
sfc /scannnow
```

command and didn't get any reports.

Do you have any idea what might cause this problem?

UPDATE:
I re-installed the app for the third time, and updated my .NET framework, and it solved my problem (i'm guessing the .NET framework update solved it, but maybe the re-installation helped :))

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server? If so, you might need to tell github so by `$ git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080`

Comment: Nope, i'm not behing a proxy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, .NET framework update worked for me. No need to reinstall the GitHub Windows client.  [Check this thread](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2044)

Comment: I update my .NET Framework but it not work.

Comment: This does not answer the question, as the link goes to gitextensions repository, not GitHub for Windows.